# Get current ajax url and dynamically create link to corresponding page in a different language

Tags: php, ajax, header

I am working on a website that uses a hashchange ajax navigation.  The urls look something like this:

domain.com/#contact.html

etc...

The site is going to exist in several languages and i want to place the language menu outside of the ajax content div, in the header for instance (a part of the page that stays the same).

My question is how can I get the current url and modify it to dynamically create links to corresponding pages in different languages.

So if the current page is "domain.com/#contact.html" I would want the language links in the header to dynamically point to something like "domain.com/fr/#contact.html (for french language) and so on.

Is this the best way to do this?

and if so, how should i go about it?

thanks for any help.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

What about replace language code in all links?

using jQuery it would be something like this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
   // use some regexp to get and replace language code in $(this).attr('href')
   $(this).attr('href') = replace_langcode($(this).attr('href'), language);
});
```